# When switching tabs removing All Child View Controllers and Move to Parent View Controller swift

Tags: swift

I am using tabBarControllers. I have 4 tabs (Home, profile, alert and setting). Setting tab has multiple child view controllers.

when i get notification it navigate to Home child controller, What I want is that when I am on a child view controller and switch tab back and forth, it will move back to parent view controller.

i want to remove child controller when i click on tab

Answer (score 0):

I really struggle to understand what you want to achieve, put if you want to pop all the `ViewController`s in the `NavigationController` stack, you can call

```
self.navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```